# Three boats and their fishing habits

Tags: calculus

### Problem:

> Assume we have three boats $A$, $B$, $C$. Their position after some
>     time $t$ is given as $$ A=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}x = 5 - t \\ y =
>   {t^2} - 5t + 6 \\ \end{array} \right. \ \ B=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}x
>   = 5{t^2} + 10t \\ y = {t^2} + t \\ \end{array}\right.\ \ C=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}x =  - 7t + 3 \\y = t \\ \end{array} \right. $$  Let
>   $T = \Delta ABC$ be the area between the boats. After what time is $t$
>   minimized?

Not quite sure where to start. I tried to express the area in terms of $t$ and taking the derivative.. Alas the answer got very messy very fast. Is there perhaps a more clever way to find it, or do some numerical approximations?

Answer (score 0):

The area is a determinant $a = \det (\vec{AB}, \vec{AC})$. That gives you a polynomial in $t$ whose variations you can study.

After trying that on wolfram alpha, it looks as if the signs of the area flips, which would mean that at some point they are colinear and hence the area is zero.